# Cannot set Chrome as Default Browser - Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, google-chrome, default-browser

I cannot set Chrome as the default browser on Lubuntu 20.04. Technical info:-
LXQt Desktop Toolbox - Technical Info:-

```
  LXQt Version:           0.14.1
  Qt:                     5.12.8
  Build type:             Release
  System Configuration:   /etc/xdg
```

Everytime I open chrome, it says that it is not the default broswer. Even though I click on `Set as Default`, it still gives the error. I have already selected chrome as the default browser in `Preferences > Session settings > Default Application` to `/usr/bin/google-chrome`. This error came after I cleared the browser cache and cookies.

Comment: I'll suggest you read and try what is suggested in this post on Lubuntu's discourse - https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/solved-chromium-google-chrome-keeps-nagging-about-not-being-the-default-browser/500

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is just [Gabriel's found on the Lubuntu discourse site](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/solved-chromium-google-chrome-keeps-nagging-about-not-being-the-default-browser/500)

> Configuring `x-www-browser` in Alternatives, XDG's
> `default-web-browser` and Lubuntu's default internet browser
> application in Session Settings is not enough. Turns out Chrome looks
> at `/etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu/mimeapps.list` and you have to edit it as
> sudo and replace the instances of the "firefox" string with your
> browser of choice.
>
> Hope I've been of some help.

Thanks should go to Gabriel (printfgabriel)

Comment: Lubuntu documented this somewhere, but I found this first.

Comment: Another answer can be found here too - https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/chrome-as-default-browser/1557

Comment: Thanks to Gabriel and @guiverc. First answer worked for me.